# Getters and setters for the properties of the object ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Where can I register getters and setters for the properties of the object ViewBag?

Answer (score 2):

ViewBag is a [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) which essentially means that the properties and values are determined at runtime. The simplest explanation is that of a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

`ViewBag.Name = "Title";` and `ViewDictionary["Name"] = "Title";` are essentially the same. As such there are no getters and setters for the ViewBag specifically. DynamicObjects.

What is it you're trying to accomplish?